# How to find MAX with a cursor in a loop

Tags: plsql

I need to find the account which has the maximum of favorited videos but im not sure how to increment the account id to loop throught all the accounts.

I know how to find the number of favorited videos per account.

```
DECLARE 
    userid  NUMBER(3) := 2; 
    CURSOR items IS 
      SELECT id_account 
      FROM   favorites; 
    counter NUMBER(3) := 0; 
BEGIN 
    FOR x IN items LOOP 
        IF x.id_account = userid THEN 
          counter := counter + 1; 
        END IF; 
    END LOOP; 

    dbms_output.Put_line(counter); 
END;
```

**Edit1** : Thanks for the responses but i forgot to mention that i must use a cursor as a goal to practise

Here is my table favorites(id_account[PK, FK], id_video[PK, FK])

**Edit2** : Thank you this is exactly want i wanted

Comment: Account id is fetching from Table rite? so you need to update it at the end of program or may i know the purpose of account id increment?

Comment: I wanted to increment the id to get the amount of favorited videos for each acccount by using my loop counter. This is the only way i thought it might work

Comment: videos and all is your scenario... tell me one thing.. **id** means **id_account** which is from 'favorites' table rite? ur qustn is not related with code and what u asked? kindly clarify your exact requirement, share your table structure ,then only we will help you out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to complicate things using PL/SQL when simple SQL can do this for you.

For instance, this query will give you account ids and number of favorite videos, sorted by number of favorite videos (from greatest number to lowest):

```
select id_account, count(*)
  from favorites
 group by id_account
 order by 2 desc;
```

Now you need to decide what to do if more than one account have the same amount of favorite videos - will you show them all, or just one (randomly)?

The following query will return only one account:

```
select *
  from (select id_account, count(*) num_fav_videos
          from favorites
         group by id_account
         order by 2 desc)
 where rownum = 1;
```

Please note that these queries will not be particularly efficient - they have to aggregate data for every single account id and than sort data.

[Edit] Since the requirement is to use cursors (I do not agree with that requirement!), you can use one cursor to go through loop, and store intermediate data in separate variables.

In the example below I set counter and maximum count to 0, and then go through all accounts that are stored in the table that links accounts and favorite videos. I store current account id and increment number of videos for that account until account in cursor changes or I get to the last row. I then compare number of favorite videos of that account to the current maximum number of videos, and if it is greater I store new maximum number of videos and account id.

```
declare
  cursor items is
    select id_account
      from favorites
     order by id_account;

  id_account_curr number;
  id_account_max  number;
  max_count number;
  counter number;
begin
  counter := 0;
  max_count := 0;
  for x in items loop
    if x.id_account = id_account_curr then -- while account is the same increment number of favorite videos
      counter := counter + 1;
    else
      if counter > max_count then
        max_count := counter;
        id_account_max := id_account_curr;
      end if;
      id_account_curr := x.id_account; -- change current account id
      counter := 1; -- practice question: why is counter set to 1 and not 0?
    end if;
  end loop;
  if counter > max_count then -- practice question: what is this for?
    max_count := counter;
    id_account_max := id_account_curr;
  end if;
  dbms_output.put_line('id_account: ' || to_char(id_account_max) || ', count: ' || to_char(max_count));
end;
```

Comment: This is exaclty what i need to do but i can't use aggregate functions. Do you mind showing me a way to do it with a cursor ? Thanks

Comment: That requirement is ridiculous - using loops this way is ok for some other languages (say, Pascal), but when working with databases you should write code that is most efficient for databases - which means write SQL queries instead of using cursors and loops in PL/SQL whenever it is appropriate. This is just the wrong example for practicing loops. That said, you can solve this using only one cursor, but data would have to be sorted by account id, and you should store intermediate data (current account id, max number of favorites, account id with max favorites) in separate variables.